# pgAdmin4 not starting on Ubuntu18.04(ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, pgadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nmUs.png)I am having the following Issue, trying to run pgAdmin4.py

sudo python3 pgAdmin4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pgAdmin4.py", line 40, in 
    import config
  File "/home/seba/pgadmin/pgadmin4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py", line 29, in 
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_PY2, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/home/seba/pgadmin/pgadmin4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/**init**.py", line 21, in 
    from flask_babelex import Babel, gettext
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_babelex'**

allthough flask-babel is installed successfully 
(pip install Flask-BabelEx)

Can anyone give me a hint, how can i solve this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and even after install all the libraries it does not disappear.
Maybe your solution is downgrade psycopg2 2.8.1 to 2.7.7 (pip install psycopg2==2.7.7) or update pgAdmin version.

Comment: This sounds a bit speculative.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by not making virtualenv as given in pgadmin4 README, instead use `python3 -m venv pgadmin4` and install all dependencies in this.

If you use `python setup.py` you may run in authorization error ,
with sudo python setup.py`enter code here` , you get :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_babelex'

Instead get yourself in root by `su -`, or `sudo bash` then `sudo -i` 
and then run `python setup.py`.